# Creating relationships in firebase using AngularFire

Tags: firebase

I am trying to create neat relationships but am finding it rather difficult to add a child on an already created array in firebase. I want to easily be able to create arrays in a child property based on the `$id` of another array.

the structure i am looking for is like so

```
foo
  -Jy7ULZGVepTGe2Dp-9Q
    - name: Manages
    - foobar
       - Jy7hbJP1aWWlOSfeXJC : true // this is johns $id
       - Jy7UQms89ycibPxDhMp : true // this is jacks $id

foobar
  - Jy7hbJP1aWWlOSfeXJC
     - name : john
  - Jy7UQms89ycibPxDhMp
     - name : jack
```

What i am currently doing is

```
 var foobar = GetObjects.getParentUrl('foobar'); // returns a $firebaseObject

     branches.name = vm.entityChild.name; // This add works
     branches.$add(branches)
        .then(function (data) {
            console.log('success: ' + data)
            var id = data.key(); // returns the id 
            var foo = GetObjects.getParentChildren('foo','foobar');
            var newFoo = foo.child(id);

            newFoo.$save(true);
        })
```

I get the error `$save is not a function`

I am not too sure if this is the best why to go about it or if there is a better practice to create a "flattened" firebase structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AngularFire is built on top of [Firebase's JavaScript SDK](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/). You should only use AngularFire constructs for things that you bind to the UI. For anything else, use the regular Firebase JavaScript SDK.

I'm guessing that `GetObjects.getParentChildren('foo','foobar')` returns a [`Firebase` object](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/firebase/). This is an object from Firebase's JavaScript SDK, so you cannot invoke AngularFire methods on it.

Instead, you call methods from the Firebase JavaScript SDK, such as: [`child()`](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/firebase/child.html) and https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/firebase/set.html:

```
var foo = GetObjects.getParentChildren('foo','foobar');
var newFoo = foo.child(id);

newFoo.set(true);
```